# WebSite deploy with on-premises TFS to IIS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

For a last seven days I'm working/playing with TFS on-premises in my company and trying to make auto build and deployment to work but somehow I can't find any source on internet how to do that. Every tutorial is about Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online).

Projects are building fine, but facing problem with deployment. 
I get lost with all of these steps "Copy files", Pulbish Artifacts etc.

Maybe somebody knows something about this or have link to article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Build Argument to build and deploy the code to a server. See a sample build argument below:

```
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=<SERVERNAME> /p:DeployIisAppPath=<IISPATH> /p:UserName=<USERNAME> /p:Password=<PASSWORD> /p:DeployOnBuild=True /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:EnableMSDeployBackup=true
```

Also, to enable the webdeploy in the server, you will have to do as below:

1. Install Web Platform Installer in the server
   https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx
2. Using the web plat form installer, install the below softwares:

   - WebDeploy 3.6
   - Windows Management Service (if not installed already)
3. Open IIS, from the IIS Home, select -> Management Service
4. In the Windows Management Service,

   - Select the option -> Enable Remote Connections
   - Select the option -> Identity Credentials as “Windows Credentials or IIS Manager credentials”
   - Now, click on Apply
   - Start the service
5. Now from IIS Home, goto -> IIS Manager User

   - Create a new User and assign a password
6. Goto the individual website Home (website to which the deployment needs to happen), goto -> IIS Manager Permissions and add the above user using the Allow User option. This needs to be done for all the websites that are required to be enabled for TFS build and Deployment
7. Now, right click on each of the websites and click Edit Permissions. Add the User -> LOCAL SERVICE to the list of users with full permission
8. Now, goto IIS Home and then select -> Configuration Editor

   - Select section -> system.webServer/wdeploy/backup from the list
   - Enter the backupPath. This will be the path when the backups will be kept before deploying
   - Select the setting -> enabled as True
   - Select the setting -> turnedOn as True
   - Select the numberOfBackups
   - Now click on Apply

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm wondering should I use Release management or should I use build definition to deploy to server? 
I really confuse since MS updating very often their products

Comment: I am not sure how we can use Release Management

Answer (score 0):

I usually get a [web deploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx) working inside visual studio and then edit the build definition to include ms build arguments (Process> 2. Build > 5. Advaced> MSBuild arguments) to invoke that publish profile.  Something like this:

```
/tv:14.0 /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:Password="[PUBLISH PASSWORD GOES HERE]" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[PROFILE YOU SET UP IN VISUAL STUDIO]
```

[this](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/12/04/Simple-Deployment-With-WebDeploy-MSBuild-TFS-co/) is a good article.